# If $p^2$ is even then $p$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Let $p^2=6$. Is $\sqrt{6}$ even?

I believe $\sqrt{6}$ is not even an integer. Could you help me find the flaw in this statement. Thanks.

Comment: Please use mathjax. I edited the post for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Even" and "odd" are properties of integers, not of arbitrary real numbers.  The correct statement is "if $p$ is an integer and $p^2$ is even, then $p$ is even."

Someone might omit the "if $p$ is an integer" part if they think it is obvious from the context.  But apparently it was not obvious to you.

Comment: Thanks Robert..

Answer (score 2):

As Robert noted, this is only true if $p$ is an integer.

Here is a proof:

Let $p$ be an integer and $p^2$ be even, so $p^2 = 2a$ for some integer $a$. Consider $p^2 + p = p(p+1)$. We know that $p(p+1)$ must be even because regardless of if $p$ is even, we will have an $\text{even} \cdot \text{odd}$, which must be even. Thus $p^2 + p = 2b$ for some integer $b$. Now note that $p = (p^2 + p) - p^2 = 2b - 2a = 2(b-a)$, where $b, a$ are integers and $b>a$. So $p$ must be even.

Comment: Thanks for this proof.

Comment: can we prove that "if h is n integer and $h^2$ has a factor of 7 then $h$ also has a factor of 7" using a similar argument?

Answer (score 0):

For integral $p$ we can also obtain this result by noting that the square of an odd integer must be odd:  if

$p = 2k + 1, \tag 1$

then

$p^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 = 2(2k^2 + 2k) + 1, \tag 2$

also odd.  Therefore if $p^2$ is even, $p$ cannot be odd, hence is also even.

Comment: Sure is true. Thanks.

Comment: I'm gratified that the mighty Sir Isaac recognizes this!  Cheers!